# how to do contour filled with few random points inside a square?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a square of 10 by 8, and I have 7 points inside this square with some values. I'd like to plot contour lines or filled contour with these 7 points values. I was using MATLAB with many points before. Now I am using Python with only 7 points. Here is the scratch codes I am thinking to do. Can you help me with it?
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate as scipy

XX_Uniform=np.linspace(0,10,100)
YY_Uniform=np.linspace(0,8,100)
xg,yg=np.meshgrid(XX_Uniform,YY_Uniform)
print(xg)
xdata=np.array([3,10,1,4,9.5,2.5,9])
ydata=np.array([7,8,5,4,3.5,1,0.5])
zdata=np.array([10,1,20,25,10,15,5])
points=np.column_stack((xdata,ydata))
#zg=scipy.griddata(xdata,ydata,zdata,xg,yg)
grid=np.c_[xg.ravel(),yg.ravel()]
zg=scipy.griddata(points,zdata.ravel(),grid)
print('zg=')
print(zg)
plot1=plt.contourf(xg,yg,zg)
plt.show()
```

after that, I keep getting the error of

```
  File "C:\Users\yongn\Python\opencv4\gps_contour.py", line 26, in <module>
    plot1=plt.contourf(xg,yg,zg)

TypeError: Input z must be 2D, not 1D
```

I just found the reason is: zg didn't get correct values from griddata, it is empty.

```
zg=[nan nan nan ... nan nan  1.]
```

Comment: Which library are you using? (for plotting in Python, matplotlib is popular, but there's also pyqtgraph and others)

Comment: thanks user202729. I am using matplotlib and seaborn. and recently I am learning opencv.

Comment: Please post the full error traceback so it is easier to help you

Comment: Maybe `plt.tricontourf(xdata, ydata, zdata)` generates what you're intending?

Comment: Yes JohanC, it works. very simple without using griddata. That is awesome, man! I really appreciate it.

Comment: And also, you can use `plot1=plt.contourf(xg, yg, zg.reshape(xg.shape))`.

Comment: Thanks gepcel, what is the difference with plot1=plt.contourf(xg, yg, zg)? I think it is the same with zg=scipy.griddata((xdata,ydata),zdata,(xg,yg)). Am I correct?